# Why is $F(x)$ continuous at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let

$$f(x) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  x  & \mbox{if } x < 0 \\
  \sin x & \mbox{if } x \ge 0
 \end{array}
\right.$$

$F(x)$ the anti-derivative should be $\frac{x^2}{2} + C_1$ for $x>0$ and $-\cos x + C_2$ for $x<0$. Now, I've understood that $F(x)$ must be continuous at $x=0$.

Why?

Comment: If it is not continuous at $x=0$ then it is not differentiable at $x=0$ so cannot serve as antiderivative there. Btw, if $f(x)=x$ for $x<0$ then $F(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}+C_1$ for $x<0$. Not for $x>0$ as you say in your question.

Comment: in Other words if function is continuous that is not guarantee for us derivation exist but if derivative is exist in every point of domain function is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want $F'(x) = f(x)$ for every $x$, then necessarily $F$ has to be continuous because diffentiable functions are continuous.

If you do not work out the constants so that $F$ is continuous at $0$ you would be able to say $F'(x) = x$ for $x < 0$ and $F'(x) = \sin(x)$ for $x > 0$, but it would not be true at $0$.

Another more explicit way to look at this is to compute the limit definition of the derivative and observe that if $F$ is discontinuous at $0$ the right and left limits for the derivative at $0$ will not agree.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very general result, that
$$
x\to \int_a^x f(u) du
$$
is a continuous function. Here, you are in the case where $f$ is itself continuous. Hence, if
$y<x$:
$$
\left|
\int_a^x f(u) du - \int_a^y f(u) du \right|
= \left|\int_y^x f(u) du \right|
\le \int_y^x |f(u)| du \le M|x-y|
$$
with $M = \sup_{u\in [x,y]} |f(u)|$ (this is defined because $f$ is continuous).

Hence
$$
x\to \int_a^x f(u) du
$$
is Lipschitz continuous.